# How to securely use service account credentials in an Android App

Tags: authentication, android, account-security, mobile-app

I have an Android application distributed to my users through an .apk file. That app collects some data, and my goal is to upload that data to a cloud service, like BigQuery. To achieve this, I am using my BigQuery's service account credentials, and at this moment, they are hardcoded into my code. I thought about encrypting them, but the encryption/decryption keys would be stored in the app anyways.

I am a Junior developer and I've done some extensive research on this, but couldn't find any solutions. It feels like every option has room for hackers to steal my credentials.

Is there a solid way to deal with this? Is using service accounts the best approach here? Which solutions can I search for?

I'd already be very happy if anyone would at least point me in some direction, give me a topic to search, or anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should not embed secrets into the code. Use [Authorization Code Flow with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)](https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/guides/auth-flow-pkce).

Answer (score 0):

Fire up a server on any VPS which will be a gateway between your users and your database back-end.

Trying to hide credentials in the app cannot and won't work.